Extract information from dot separated hierarchical list
I am trying to extract a value (nread) from sysctl, but only for a specific dataset_name. What is the most efficient way to do this with a shell script?
Example sysctl output (via "sysctl kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset"):
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x60.nread: 15968172
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x60.dataset_name: zroot/usr/home
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x87.nread: 20587076
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x87.dataset_name: zroot/tmp
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x51.nread: 95249410985
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x51.dataset_name: zroot/ROOT/default


Please [edit] your question and specify the condition and expected output matching your example. As you asked for "the most efficient way to do this with a shell script": Is your solution not efficient enough? Or what specific requirements for the efficiency do you have?

Possible solution using awk:
Pipe the data into
awk '/\.nread:/ { n=$2 } $2 == "zroot/tmp" { print n }'

to show the number above zroot/tmp.
This script relies on the order of the lines as shown in the question, specifically that the corresponding lines are in the order shown below. Other lines in between will be ignored.
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x87.nread: 20587076
kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset.objset-0x87.dataset_name: zroot/tmp

If you have to handle different cases, show appropriate examples in the question. Then the script might get more complicated.

Before giving an answer, it is important to be sure of what the expected output is and what exactly is meant by 'specific dataset name' and 'efficient'. Perhaps your answer addresses these things but that can't be known until the aforementioned information have been provided.

this also relies on the lines being always in that particular order. Which I'm mostly mentioning since nread and dataset_name seem to be in reverse sort order there, which seems a bit odd. Anyway, it's probably a good idea to be explicit about the constraints and assumptions you make.

Could be something like:
sysctl kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset |
  perl -slne '
    $f{$1}->{$2} = $3 if /^\S+\.(\S+)\.(\S+): (.*)/;
    END {
      print $_->{$field} for grep {$_->{dataset_name} eq $name} values %f
    }' -- -name=zroot/tmp -field=nread

For instance to get the nread value for datasets whose name is zroot/tmp.

With jq:
sysctl kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset |
  jq --arg name zroot/tmp --arg field nread -rRs '
    reduce capture("(?m:^(?<key>\\S+): (?<value>.*)$)"; "g") as $l (
      {}; setpath($l.key|split("."); $l.value)
    ) |
      .kstat.zfs.zroot.dataset[] |
      select(.dataset_name == $name).[$field]'

For instance to get the nread value for zroot datasets whose name is zroot/tmp.
